# R Shiny : group variables under a unique label and use that label in reactive output

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a dataframe with about 60 columns and I would like to make a Principal Components Analysis (PCA) but only with some columns. Is there a way to regroup those columns under a unique label and to call that label in a reactive output ?

Here's a reproducible example :

- first of all : we create two subgroups in mtcars (CAT1 and CAT2) and create a vector containing the names of the columns (all of those packages are not necessary)

```
library(easypackages)
libraries("readxl", "tidyselect", "DT", "shiny", "treemap", "plm", "shinydashboard", "data.table", "formattable", "plotly", "FactoMineR", "factoextra")

CAT1 <- mtcars[, 3:5]
CAT2 <- mtcars[, 5:8]
noms1 <- names(CAT1)
noms2 <- names(CAT2)
```

- then, we make the UI, where we put the two vectors containing names in `choices`:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "test with mtcars", titleWidth = 1000),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectizeInput("var.acp", "PCA variables", 
                   choices = c("noms1", "noms2"),
                   selected = "noms1", multiple = FALSE),
    selectizeInput("sample", "Sample", choices = unique(rownames(mtcars)), 
                   selected = rownames(mtcars), multiple = TRUE)
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("test with mtcars",
               box(title = "PCA mtcars",
                   status = "primary",
                   solidHeader = TRUE,
                   collapsible = TRUE,
                   dataTableOutput("pca"),
                   width = 12)
               )
      )
    )
  )
```

- finally, here's the code for the output I would like to create :

```
  server <- function(input, output) {

    sample.choice <- reactive({
      out <- input$sample
      out
    })

    acp <- reactive({
      out <- input$var.acp
      out
    })

    user.selection <- reactive({
      data.user <- mtcars[rownames(mtcars) %in% sample.choice(), ]
      data.user <- mtcars[, acp()]
    })

    output$pca <- renderDataTable({
      dpca <- user.selection()
      dpca <- na.omit(dpca)
      tmp <- prcomp(dpca, scale = TRUE)
      tmp <- data.table(get_eig(tmp))
      tmp
    })
  }


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The output is supposed to be a table containing the eigenvalues of the PCA realized on each of the two subgroups of `mtcars`.
However, I get an error : `undefined columns selected`. The error must be with `data.user <- mtcars[, acp()]` but this is strange, because `mtcars` recognizes the columns when I call them :

```
head(mtcars[, noms1])

    # disp  hp drat
    # Mazda RX4          160 110 3.90
    # Mazda RX4 Wag      160 110 3.90
    # Datsun 710         108  93 3.85
    # Hornet 4 Drive     258 110 3.08
    # Hornet Sportabout  360 175 3.15
    # Valiant            225 105 2.76
```

Is there a way to fix this ? (sorry if the message is a little bit long)

Comment: Your code does `mtcars[, "noms1"]`, not `mtcars[, noms1]`.

Comment: right, so how can I change this ? When I replace `""` by `''` in `selectizeInput`, it does not change anything

Comment: Use `switch` like this: `switch(input$var.acp, "noms1"=noms1, "noms2"=noms2)`

Comment: I've never used this function, where should I put it ?

Comment: In your reactive conductor `acp`.

Comment: it works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Stéphane Laurent's answer, here's how to fix it :

```
    acp <- reactive({
      out <- switch(input$var.acp, "noms1"=noms1, "noms2"=noms2)
      out
    })
```

instead of

```
    acp <- reactive({
      out <- input$var.acp
      out
    })
```

in `server`.